# Поиск с помощью .loc[ ] и вывод строки в боте телеграм

Tags: python, excel, pandas, telegram-bot, telebot

Какое значение необходимо указать в `first = data.loc[]` и `second = data.loc[]`, чтобы при поиске юнита, мы вводили имя, допустим - Лучник, и он выводил бы следующее сообщение столбиком:

Имя существа Лучник
Уровень 2 
Атака 6 
Защита 3 
Урон 2-3 
Здоровье 10 
Скорость 4 
Прирост 9 
Цена 100 золота
 И так с любым другим юнитом. Так же и с артефактами. Вводим например Ребра и нам выводит:
 Название артефакта Ребра 
Характеристики Сила +2

Код полностью:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
import pandas as pd

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("6745636************")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Найти юнит')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Найти артефакт')
 
    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "{0.first_name}, выберите вариант.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def find_unit(message):
    try:
      if message.text == 'Найти юнит':
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите название существа, которое нужно найти. Важно: писать название нужно точно, без ошибок.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, unit)

      elif message.text == 'Найти артефакт':
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите название артефакта, который нужно найти. Важно: писать название нужно точно, без ошибок.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, artifact)

    except: 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка! Не найдено')

def unit(message):
    data = pd.read_excel("database.xlsx", sheet_name='units', index_col ='Имя существа') 
    first = data.loc[**?**]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, first)

def artifact(message):
    data = pd.read_excel("database.xlsx", sheet_name='artifacts', index_col ='Название артефакта') 
    second = data.loc[**?**]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, second)


bot.polling()
```

Содержание файла [database.xlsx](https://dropmefiles.com/NDTSI)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [75]: un = pd.read_excel(r"D:\download\database.xlsx", sheet_name='units', index_col ='Имя существа')

In [76]: art = pd.read_excel(r"D:\download\database.xlsx", sheet_name='artifacts', index_col='Название артефакта')

In [77]: un.loc['Лучник']
Out[77]:
id              bowman
Уровень              2
Атака                6
Защита               3
Урон               2-3
Здоровье            10
Скорость             4
Прирост              9
Цена        100 золота
Name: Лучник, dtype: object

In [78]: art.loc['Ребра']
Out[78]:
Характеристики    Сила +2
Name: Ребра, dtype: object
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за задержку. При применении Вашего ответа он ругается на эту же строчку и пишет KeyError 'Имя существа'. Это происходит именно после того когда я ввожу имя, после сообщения 'Напишите название существа, которое нужно найти..'

Comment: @octopoto, можете выложить пример Excel файла на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Да, конечно.
https://dropmefiles.com/NDTSI

Comment: @octopoto, не заметил, что вы указали `index_col='Имя существа'` - соответственно у вас нет столбца `'Имя существа'` - это теперь индекс

Comment: Теперь работает, спасибо! Можете пожалуйста подсказать еще, что стоит сделать, если необходимо вывести в таком же виде другое существо или артефакт. Иными словами изначально не прописывая конкретное значение в un.loc[], а позволяя мне определять его самому. Допустим я ввожу имя грифон, и он выдает все характеристики строки из листа units, где упоминается имя грифон. Ну и так же по аналогии с любым другим существом, имя которого я могу ввести. Лучником, копейщиком и т.д.

Comment: @octopoto, вы имеете ввиду: `name = 'Грифон'; un.loc[name]` ?

Comment: К примеру я использую input, где он равен значению из "Имя существа'
Ввел в строку Грифон, он выдал мне значение un.loc если бы там стояло значение ['Грифон']
Затем ввел в строку Лучник, получил то, что программа должна выдать из un.loc если бы там стояло значение ['Лучник'].
Просто никак не могу додуматься как это сделать.

Comment: @octopoto, я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать. Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос с примерами ввода пользователя и вывода, который вы хотите получить

Comment: Хорошо, позже создам. Спасибо вам, что помогли с текущим вопросом и потратили свое время!